# Oracle: How to assign ROW_NUMBER() base on condition in select

Tags: sql, oracle

So i trying to use 1 procedure to use for both search all which return all col and search using key work to return just 1 col in a table and group them by page. The thing is using search by key work return a lot of duplicate result in desired col. I'm trying to assign row number to the select table to differently base on condition of key work as a key to do filter later on but it won't work.

```
SELECT
        *
        FROM
        (
          SELECT
            TOTALRECORD,
            nRow,
            PRODUCTID,
            PRODUCTNAME,
            STOREID,
            STORENAME,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY nRow ORDER BY MASTERDATA.PM_PRODUCT_STOCKLIMIT.PRODUCTID) filter
          FROM
          (
            SELECT
              NVL2(v_txtSearch,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY MASTERDATA.PM_PRODUCT_STOCKLIMIT.STOREID) AS nRow,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY MASTERDATA.PM_PRODUCT_STOCKLIMIT.PRODUCTID) AS nRow),                  
              COUNT(*) OVER() TOTALRECORD,...
                   ))
      WHERE
     (nRow BETWEEN (t_PageNum * v_RecNum) AND ((t_PageNum + 1) * v_RecNum -1) or v_PageNum=0)
      AND filter = 1
```

So how do you implement it? or should i try another approach? I also did try case and if-else but it may have wrong syntax or can't use in select O_O

i trying to do something like

```
    If v_keywork = null just make normal row number no partition and return
 normal product/ store relationship order by store id
 Filter - nROW - PRODUCTID - StoreID
    1   |  1    | a        |  1
    1   |  2    | b        |  1
    1   |  3    | a        |  2
    1   |  4    | b        |  3

    If v_keywork != null partion by product id so later i use that filter to remove 
duplicate product ID for searching product that have been stored in specific stores order by productID
 Filter - nROW - PRODUCTID - StoreID
    1   |  1    | a        |  1
    2   |  2    | a        |  2
    1   |  3    | b        |  1
    2   |  4    | b        |  3
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking here.  Please at least show us some sample input and output.

Comment: well 1st timer so i'm a little confuse X_X. The real code and table is very big ( most of which not wrote by me), the page num and record num is used to show limited data to view in asp.net